# How to split a buffer in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

The buffer was converted in to string by toString.

now i have a string that looks something like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
....
```

how can i parse it every time there is a space (" ") or that a new row is started?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: localhost:8080\nConnection: keep-alive\nCache-Control: max-age=0";

str.split(/\s/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the char before host.

```
var index = str.indexOf("Host");
str = str.subString(index,str.length-1); // this will take string from Host only.
var stringArray = str.split("\n");

var host = stringArray[1].split(": ")[0];
var url = stringArray[1].split(": ")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var regex = new RegExp("[\s\n]");
var myarray = mystr.split(regex);
```